# Symfony2 - Find tagged services in command

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, command, symfony-2.1

I would like to know if there is a way to find tagged services in Command.

I have a Command that extends `ContainerAwareCommand`, I'm able to get to container but I would like to get all services that is tagged by a specific tag. For example, I'd like to have something like that:

```
$this->getContainer()->findTaggedServiceIds('smtp.transport')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tagged services are only available at build-time of the dependency injection container, not at run-time. So, to get all services with a certain tag you will need to build a compiler pass that saves a list of these services which you can then latter use in your command. This is all described in this document:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

Comment: Yes, I have already a compiler pass that I added via $container->addCompilerPass() in my Bundle. The problem is that I could not find a way to get the ContainerBuilder in Command so that I could call addCompilerPass(). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ah Ok, I've got it. I have multiple apps that have multiple AppKernel, just have to call the right app that load the bundle. Thank you very much.