# Symfony: findTaggedServiceIds() returns empty array

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I my symfony 2.1 project I want to use findTaggedServiceIds() inside a custom service.

The service:

```
class GetServiceMaps 
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct($container) 
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getServices()
    {  
        $taggedServices = $this->container->findTaggedServiceIds(
            'efg_statistic.service');

        return $taggedServices;
    }
}
```

My service.yml:

```
parameters:
efg_identity.get_where_dql.class: \GetWhereDql
efg_statistic.get_service_maps.class: \GetServiceMaps
symfony.container_builder.class: \ContainerBuilder

services:
   symfony.container_builder:
   class: %symfony.container_builder.class%

   .get_where_dql:
   class: %efg_identity.get_where_dql.class%
   calls:
     - [getMapping, ["@efg_identity.get_where_dql"]]
   tags: 
     - { name: efg_statistic.service }

   .get_service_maps:
   class: %efg_statistic.get_service_maps.class%
   arguments: ["@symfony.container_builder"]
```

My problem is that calling

```
$taggedServices = $container->getServices();
```

returns an empty array. I guess it has something to do with the fact that I inject a new instance of ContainerBuilder, but in order to call findTaggedServiceIds I don't know how to get around it.

The use of a compiler pass with CompilerInterface unfortunately is not an option for me.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okidok,

the problem is that there is just no way around using the CompilerPass Interface when looking for tagged Services.

Tags are only available during compile-time, meaning the container only implements TaggedContainerInterface during compile time.

See here:

[Symfony2 - Find tagged services in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211396/symfony2-find-tagged-services-in-command)
http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/TaggedContainerInterface.html
http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html